# Number of row of worksheet with different number of row for each column

Tags: r

I have a csv file containing 2 column with different amount of data, this data is called Belasting and it looks like:

```
a   b
1   3
3   6
2   6
4   7
    8
    8
    9
```

It can be seen that the number of row for "a" is 4 and for b is "7". The problem is when I use the command `nrow`, it will give zero result such as:

```
nrow(belasting$a)
NULL
```

Which function should I use and how to write it?

Comment: can you provide the result of `str(belasting)`?

Answer (score 1):

if you are wanting "length" of a vector - try `length(belasting$a)`

if you want rows of the dataset, try `nrow(belasting)`

as such your data is inconsistent - `data <- data.frame(a = c(1 , 2 , 3, 4), b = c(1 , 2, 3, 4 , 5, 6, 6))` if you try this you will be returned an error. You cannot ask for "number of rows of a worksheet with different number of rows for each column".

Comment: @Yuwardi, if you import your csv into R, a consistent table will be created and NA will be added to the last three cells of the column a